# Discrepancy during saving an Ajax page to disk

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I was trying to save a URL to disk by right clicking on the page but the saved page does not have the text I see in the browser. I am using firefox. This is a pretty regular page rendered with text obtained by a JS call after the page is loaded.

Here is the URL - www.chilis.com/EN/Pages/menu.aspx

When I open it in the browser I see some menu items but when I save the page to disk and then open it I don't see the menu items. I understand that the CSS, JS and images are there as links and so they will not be there in the saved file. But I expect the text to be there. Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause are the browser security settings. Since you are serving the file from disk, many requests will be cross-domain. Try serving the file from your own web-server and see what happens. Also, have a look at the console when accessing the page from disk. The error messages will help.

Answer (score 0):

The menu items are there - you cannot see the *text* because it is out of alignment because of `css text-indent property`. the shown texts on their website are images set as css background (these can of course not be found/loaded by url(givenpath)):

[image]

Comment: If I open the saved file in a texteditor should I not be able to see the text? I do not.

Comment: Yea you should. I did the same - save the file to disk (using firefox 24.0) and opened it with notepad to explore the markup.. The markup of `<div class="verticalNavigation">` is completely available

Comment: Actually no. Click on the beverages menu on the left side and save the page to disk. Grep the page for "Bottomless" (that is the menu item in the page). It will not be there.